# What are the properties of this differential-like operator?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, operator-theory

So I've recently came across [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/108773/independence-of-leibniz-rule-and-locality-from-other-properties-of-the-derivative) question, which is about defining the differential operator $D_x$ in terms of axioms rather than the traditional "taking the limit"-way. This made me think about a new operator, which I will denote with $E_x$ (for no definite reason), that has the following axiomatic definition ($f,g : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ for the sake of simplicity):

$$E_x\{f \cdot g\}=E_x\{f\} \cdot E_x\{g\}$$

$$E_x\{f \times g\} = E_x\{f\} \times g \space \cdot \space E_x\{g\} \times f$$

$$E_x\{(f \circ \vec{g})(x)\} = 
\prod_{\forall g \in \vec{g}} 
\Big( E_g\{f\} \circ \vec{g} \Big)(x) \times E_x\{g\}$$

where

$$a \times b = \exp{(\ln{a} \cdot \ln{b})} = a^{\ln{b}}=b^{\ln{a}}$$

which is a commutative and associative binary operator and moreover it is distributive with multiplication (and higher in order):

$$ a \times (b \cdot c) =
\exp{\Big(\ln{a} \cdot \ln{(b \cdot c)}\Big)} = \exp{\Big(\ln{a} \cdot \ln{b}\Big)} \cdot \exp{\Big(\ln{a} \cdot \ln{c}\Big)} =
(a \times b) \cdot (a \times c)$$

So the first axiom is the "additive" linearity, the second is the Leibnitz-rule while the latter one is the chain rule. I have several questions regarding this new $E_x$ operator:

1. Is this a viable axiomatic system or it breaks down somewhere? Does it already exist or it is a new concept?
2. For what functions can it be applied to?
3. Does it also have a geometrical representation like the slope of the function in the derivative's case?
4. What happenes whet it is applied to the "basic" functions ($x^{n}$, $\sin$, $\cos$, $\exp$, etc...)?

Comment: $\times$ breaks down when functions become non-positive. Once you stay within th epositives, $f\mapsto \ln\circ f$ seems to be an isomorphism to the "traditional" situation